# How can I convert my htmlBody to plainTextBody using Apex/Regex

Tags: apex, apex-email-service, regular-expressions

The emails that are being recieved by my apex-email-service do not have plainTextBodies. Is there a way to convert HTML to PlaintextBody in apex?

Comment: Originally I was trying to auto-forward mail in plainText through gmail. Unfortunately they don't support this feature. If you manually forward the email through gmail, you can convert it to plain text. But I am trying to create a system that doesn't require manual labor. @AdrianLarson

Comment: You could try just replacing all tags with the empty string. [Sample regex](http://rubular.com/r/H8E61O92Tr): `<\/?\w*\b[^>]*>`.

Comment: So this would replace all tags and their contents. Would that really cause a complete conversion from html to plaintext? I know there may also be some CSS in there...but besides that, is this foolproof?  @AdrianLarson

Comment: Far from foolproof. You could `or` in a search for `<style>` tags and include their contents. For [example](http://rubular.com/r/4x7etU0gQx): `<style>[^<]*<\/style>|<\/?\w*\b[^>]*>`.

Comment: Ok. I will give this a shot tomorrow. I'm sure I'll have to customize it to the text. Its too bad you can't just forward mail in plainText format... I couldn't even find an email application that acts as a middleman... @AdrianLarson

Comment: @AdrianLarson Hi Adrian, I know that my regEx works to capture the group. How do I replace this grouping with ' '?

Comment: You should post that as a separate question.

Comment: stripHtmlTags() removes new line character. Method have also other bugs and it will be depricated based on the salesforce documentation. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_stripHtmlTags

Answer (score 10):

I think rather than using any RegEx, you can just use a built in String method: stripHtmlTags.

[Salesforce String Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm)

So it would look like:

```
String plainText = htmlBody.stripHtmlTags();
```

Comment: With the following caveat:
The stripHtmlTags function does not recursively strip tags; therefore, tags may still exist in the returned string. Do not use the stripHtmlTags function to sanitize input for inclusion as a raw HTML page. The unescaped output is not considered safe to include in an HTML document. The function will be deprecated in a future release.

Answer (score 3):

Just realized that I basically answered this in the comments, so it might make sense to post as a proper answer.

I would just try to replace all tags with the empty string. Example:

```
Pattern tagPattern = Pattern.compile('<\/?\w*\b[^>]*>');
String plainTextBody = tagPattern.matcher(htmlBody).replaceAll('');
```

Comment: why not just use .stripHTMLTags? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm

Comment: @techbusinessman Because I wasn't aware of that function at the time. This post is over a year old now.

Comment: Just saw that ;)

Comment: You'll also need to escape the backslash with double backslaches:
String regExp = '<style>[^<]*<\\/style>|<\\/?\\w*\\b[^>]*>';
Pattern tagPattern = Pattern.compile(regExp);
String plainTextBody = tagPattern.matcher(emailContent).replaceAll('');